# ajax post refreshes the page when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a uses jquery post answers to a grader.php script, which works perfectly. Depending on the results, it brings a form so they can send message with contact info. When I try to post to the second script to process the mailer, the whole page refreshes without posting the data or returning the appropriate message. It turns out the call is not being made at all. If you want to see the [staging site](http://mdifl.com/datedaniel/) you're welcome to look. It's kind of a cheesy way for me to get my feet wet with jquery. However, I believe the suspect script is here.

I added an alert to the click event to see if it even triggers the click on the score button. No alert triggers and all I get is a page refresh.

Alternatively, is there any way log posts and console data to see exactly what's happening?

HTML:

```
<div id="result">
    <form id="info" method="post" action="">
    <input name="phone_number" placeholder="phone number" type="text" size="20" value="">
    <input name="email_address" placeholder="email address" type="text" size="30" value="">
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Questions? Comments?" name="comments"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="score" name="score" value="Send">
    </form>';
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#score").click(function(event){
    alert("clicked");
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    var info = $("#info").serialize();
    $('#result').fadeOut().html("");
    $.post('paider.php', info, function(data , status){
        $('#result').fadeIn().html(data);
        alert(status);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried just putting it in a button rather than involving `submit` in any way?

Comment: I just tried on your suggestion, but no luck.

Comment: Try preventing the form's submit event.

Comment: event.preventDefault is in place, and so far works everywhere else it's used.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 problems here.

*Problem 1:*
As the form resides inside #result, setting #result's html to "" effectively empties the form before serialization? Have you tried?

```
$("#score").click(function(event){
    var info = $("#info").serialize();
    $('#result').fadeOut().html("");
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    $.post('paider.php', info, function(data , status){
        $('#result').fadeIn().html(data);
    });
});
```

*Problem 2:*
Okay so I took a look at your staging site and think I've found the issue. You begin by having a form similar to the one in the question on this topic, but you then "replace" that form with a new form containing now a "#score" element (input type='submit').

You are applying your jquery event handler on document load but at that time the #score element does not yet exist in the DOM because you have not loaded it yet.

You believe you are running the script inside $("#score").click but in fact the page is simply using default behavior of a form with no action and a submit button.

To correct this issue you need to apply the event handler at either a higher level in the DOM tree OR you can do some easier way just to test if this is the problem

Please try this in your first #submitbuttonclick handler

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    var formdata = $('form').serialize();
    $.post('grader.php', formdata, function(data , status){
        $('ul').css('display', 'none');
        $('#result').fadeIn().html(data);
        //Here add the handler for #score click
        $("#score").off("click").on("click", function(event){
            //Insert code snippet shared above here
        });
    });
});
```

What this will do is bind the click event on the #score submit button after it has been written into the DOM. In case the script executes more than once we do not want the handler to fire multiple times, which is why we first call "off".

Hope this helps.

Comment: But that shouldn't affect the behavior of form submit (refresh) in any way. It could solve the empty values problem, but not the refresh page problem

Comment: Please note edit. It was the declaration of the handler prior to the element being in the DOM. jQuery could not find the element so your event was not called

Comment: Thanks, that sound like it will be it. I've changed it on the staging page. It still doesn't work, but what you say makes sense. I'm probably doing it wrong, because I didn't understand binding the new element. When you add '$("#score").off("click").on("click", function(event){' isn't that the actual click function? I thought it would belong outside the #submitButton click function. I've tried it like I thought you said, and then what I thought you meant, but don't have it working.

Comment: When you declare an event in jquery, that event is attached at the time it is experienced in script to the element within the selector (in your case element '#score'. If it does not find an element with that selector no 'event handler' is attached. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ for more on how events work in jquery maybe as a start. But the code I wrote there should work assuming element exists in the DOM and can be found using the selector

Comment: For what you are doing you want to have a look at using delegates in jquery rather than event handlers http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ These live on the DOM level and work around limitations of element not existing in the DOM